# jQuery slideshow takes time load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using 7 jQuery functions to run 7 slideshows of a varying time interval in one page.

It takes the maximum value of the time interval (6s) to load all functions.

Can someone guide me on how to make them independent?

Below is the JS code.

```
$(function fn1() {
  $(".class1 img:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function fn1() {
    $(".class1 :first-child")
     .fadeOut(2500)
     .next("img")
     .fadeIn(2500)
     .end()
     .appendTo(".class1");
    }, 5000);
});

$(function fn2() {
  $(".class2 img:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function fn2() {
    $(".class2 :first-child")
     .fadeOut(2750)
     .next("img")
     .fadeIn(2750)
     .end()
     .appendTo(".class2");
    }, 5500);
});

$(function fn3() {
  $(".class3 img:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function fn3() {
    $(".class3 :first-child")
     .fadeOut(3000)
     .next("img")
     .fadeIn(3000)
     .end()
     .appendTo(".class3");
    }, 6000);
});

$(function fn4() {
  $(".class4 img:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function fn4() {
    $(".class4 :first-child")
     .fadeOut(2500)
     .next("img")
     .fadeIn(2500)
     .end()
     .appendTo(".class4");
    }, 5000);
});

$(function fn5() {
  $(".class5 img:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function fn5() {
    $(".class5 :first-child")
     .fadeOut(3000)
     .next("img")
     .fadeIn(3000)
     .end()
     .appendTo(".class5");
    }, 6000);
});

$(function fn6() {
  $(".class6 img:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function fn6() {
    $(".class6 :first-child")
     .fadeOut(2000)
     .next("img")
     .fadeIn(2000)
     .end()
     .appendTo(".class6");
    }, 4000);
});

$(function fn7() {
  $(".class7 img:gt(0)").hide();
   setInterval(function fn7() {
    $(".class7 :first-child")
     .fadeOut(2750)
     .next("img")
     .fadeIn(2750)
     .end()
     .appendTo(".class7");
    }, 5500);
});
```

In the CSS I have given display value as none for the images. So when the functions are loading with the maximum time interval value (6s), the entire page remains blank which is not desirable. I would like it to load immediately irrespective of the setInterval value.

Could anyone please guide me on this?

Comment: Sorry but could you create an example here or a fiddle? I'm not quite sure if I got you right. Thank you very much.

Comment: @kwoxer [Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/sheikishaq/9r3481qf/)

Comment: @kwoxer so if you observe, once clicking on run, the animation doesn't start immediately. It waits for 6 secs (maximum setInterval provided) before showing the images

Answer (score 0):

In assumption:

- instead of **setInterval** better use **setTimeout**
- this makes it possible to trigger it at the very beginning with the **()**

```js
$(function fn1() {
  $(".class1 img:gt(0)").hide();
  (function foo1() {
    $(".class1 :first-child")
    .fadeOut(2500)
    .next("img")
    .fadeIn(2500)
    .end()
    .appendTo(".class1");
    setTimeout(foo1, 5000);
  })();
});

$(function fn2() {
  $(".class2 img:gt(0)").hide();
  (function foo2() {
    $(".class2 :first-child")
    .fadeOut(1)
    .next("img")
    .fadeIn(1)
    .end()
    .appendTo(".class2");
    setTimeout(foo2, 5500);
  })();
});

$(function fn3() {
  $(".class3 img:gt(0)").hide();
  (function foo3() {
    $(".class3 :first-child")
    .fadeOut(3000)
    .next("img")
    .fadeIn(3000)
    .end()
    .appendTo(".class3");
    setTimeout(foo3, 6000);
  })();
});

$(function fn4() {
  $(".class4 img:gt(0)").hide();
  (function foo4() {
    $(".class4 :first-child")
    .fadeOut(2500)
    .next("img")
    .fadeIn(2500)
    .end()
    .appendTo(".class4");
    setTimeout(foo4, 5000);
  })();
});

$(function fn5() {
  $(".class5 img:gt(0)").hide();
  (function foo5() {
    $(".class5 :first-child")
    .fadeOut(3000)
    .next("img")
    .fadeIn(3000)
    .end()
    .appendTo(".class5");
    setTimeout(foo5, 6000);
  })();
});

$(function fn6() {
  $(".class6 img:gt(0)").hide();
  (function foo6() {
    $(".class6 :first-child")
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .next("img")
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo(".class6");
    setTimeout(foo6, 4000);
  })();
});

$(function fn7() {
  $(".class7 img:gt(0)").hide();
  (function foo7() {
    $(".class7 :first-child")
    .fadeOut(2750)
    .next("img")
    .fadeIn(2750)
    .end()
    .appendTo(".class7");
    setTimeout(foo7, 5500);
  })();
});
```

```css
.class1,
.class2,
.class3,
.class4,
.class5,
.class6,
.class7{
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding:2px;
  float: left;
}

.imageClass {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  animation: animateright 1s;
}

@keyframes animateright {
  from {
    right: -300px;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    right: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="class1" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="class2" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="class3" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="class4" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>

<div class="class5" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="class6" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>
<div class="class7" id="cust">
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=1" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=2" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=3" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=4" alt="" />
  <img class="imageClass" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200?text=5" alt="" />
</div>
```